# DDEV and NGINX: mixed content problem with images over SSL

Tags: nginx, ddev

I am using a custom PHP project with DDEV. The project uses NGINX as a server with two different doc roots: One doc root hosts the website code, the second is used as a CDN.
The doc roots are accessible with two urls

- site.ddev.site
- cdn.site.ddev.site

When the main domain requests images via *https* from cdn.site.ddev.site I receive an error in the Chrome console:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'site.ddev.site' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://cdn.site.ddev.site/imgXYZ.jpg'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I have read that the ddev-router acts as a reverse proxy that terminates SSL and passes along requests on port 80 to the web container which explains the *mixed content* error.

I tried a rewrite:

```
server {
     listen 80;
     server_name cdn.site.ddev.site;
     return 301 https://cdn.site.ddev.site$request_uri;
}
```

But it does not work and loops infinitely for the same reasons that ddev routes all requests to port 80.

How can I fix it? Is there kind of a proxy NGINX setting I can use to force HTTPS?

**Edit 1:**

There is a thumbnail related functionality that rewrites the url if a thumb img is missing so a new one will be generated via PHP. From that rewrite on *https* is missing and requests are made with *http*. Still I am not sure how the correct rewrite should look. The simplified *server* block:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    location ~* /img/thumbs/.*.\.(?:jpe?g|png|webp)$ {
        try_files $uri @thumb;
    }

    location @thumb {
        rewrite ^/img/thumbs/(.*) /shots/thumb/$1 redirect;
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:**

If i put this in the server block (not into location) it seems to work:

```
add_header 'Content-Security-Policy' 'upgrade-insecure-requests';
```

It's my workaround for now.

Answer (score 1):

DDEV doesn't route requests to port 80, your code is using `http://cdn.site.ddev.site/imgXYZ.jpg`  somewhere when it should be using `https://cdn.site.ddev.site/imgXYZ.jpg`. You'll have to find it. DDEV doesn't *create* traffic, it *serves* traffic, and a default setup uses https, while being willing to serve http. This is easy to prove - you should be able to hit  `https://cdn.site.ddev.site/imgXYZ.jpg` from your browser, and it should work fine.

Comment: thanks, I have found an issue with a thumbnail function inside the server block and have put that to the original question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is still your code, no rewrite should be involved. Your code should be using the correct prefix. There are server variables to tell you whether you're in https context and you should use them.